# Integrating simple PHP blogging system into existing website

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, blogs

I want to, create blog page in my website.

There are bunch of huge blogging platforms such as: Wordpress, Blogger ... But the problem is, they are offering a loads of unneeded functions. Of course, I can create simple blog. But it will cost a lots of time and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

So what I need is, "core" functions of blogging system such as:

- Adding, removing, editing posts, inserting attachments, images o posts
- Pagination

I don't want to integrate wordpress because of reasons that I explained above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try CodeIgniter's ["Create a Blog in 20 Minutes"](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/) tutorial.

Comment: @JaredFarrish so, I should integrate whole framework?

Comment: CI is designed to be very lightweight, and has the basic functionality you're describing. I think it could very well be what you're looking for. See the welcome message on their [homepage](http://codeigniter.com/).

Comment: I'm not sure that using an entire framework is a efficient if you already have a site in place. I don't know of any off hand but I'm fairly confident that there will be some lightweight PHP Blog software that you can install into an existing website without having to refactor much of your codebase.

Comment: @BenStephenson I'm already using Zend Framework for youtube api. Maybe it's possible with zend fw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used cutewnews for a while when I was new to coding (http://cutephp.com) it's pretty much the same as a blogging system. Create posts, edit posts, archive posts, categories, template is very customizable, allow/block comments, require users to register in order to add comments, block IPs, WYSIWYG editor, etc. It's all done in the back end and then you add a few lines of code in your page and the posts will appear. You can also designate how many you want to display per page. It's simple but effective and free. I believe there is a link at the bottom of the script going back to http://cutephp.com/ but you should be able to find it and delete it. It takes about 2 minutes to install and get set up. You don't even need mysql. Will work with any php frame work or coding style as long as you have the ability to create your own blank page where you can plop the code.